# Can a bash script be hooked to a file?

Tags: linux, shell, files, hook

I want a script to sleep unless a certain file is modifed/deleted (or a file created in a certain directory, or ...). Can this be achieved in some elegant way? The simplest thing that comes to my mind is a loop that sleeps for some time before checking the status again, but maybe there is a more elegant way?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

On linux, you can use the kernel's `inotify` feature. Tools for scripting can be found there: [inotify-tools](http://inotify-tools.sourceforge.net/).

Example use from wiki:

```
#!/bin/sh

EVENT=$(inotifywait --format '%e' ~/file1) # blocking without looping
[ $? != 0 ] && exit
[ "$EVENT" = "MODIFY" ] && echo 'file modified!'
[ "$EVENT" = "DELETE_SELF" ] && echo 'file deleted!'
# etc...
```

Comment: Most unices have a similar feature. Unfortunately each has its own interface, and many have no shell API.

Answer (score 4):

There is an API called [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) for C programmers.

There are some tools that use it, e.g. [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en) and [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki/).

Comment: Tremendous, that’s the stuff. Cheers Mikel!

Answer (score 3):

Indeed there is: [entr(1)](http://entrproject.org) will run arbitrary commands when files change, and also provides an auto-reload option for restarting application servers.

*edit: some examples*

Rebuild if sources files change

```
$ find *.c | entr make
```

Launch and auto-reload test server if files change

```
$ ls *.py | entr -r python main.py
```

Providing a the agument `+/path/to/fifo` allows more complex scripting by instructing `entr` to write the name of each file that changes to a named pipe. The following will convert Markdown files in the current directory to HTML as they're edited

```
$ ls *.md | entr +/tmp/notify &
$ while read F
> do
>   markdown2html $F
> done < /tmp/notify
```

Comment: Intriguing, but weird.  So ... it reads a bunch of file names on standard input, and runs the specified command when one of them changes?

Comment: Looks interesting, thanks! Is there any way to have `entr` pass on the name of the file that has changed as well?

Comment: As of the 2.7 release, the special `/_` argument (somewhat analogous to `$`_ in Perl) is replaced with the name of the first file that changed

Comment: @TobiasKienzler also, maybe you could use `xargs -I % entr <command> %` to pass the file name from the previous pipe of `find *.ext |` or use the special argument as @eradman suggests