# Is there a tool that hooks to two directories and synchronizes them as soon as something changes?

Tags: directory, synchronization

I have huge simulation directories on the two machines `server` and on `cluster` which I want to keep synchronized. The basic situation is that files rarely change but when a simulation is done many big files change at once which I'd like to have synchronized as soon as they are closed.

Therefore I assume a cronjob using rsync is not ideal, cronjob because it calls rsync at a fixed time interval which I'd probably choose either too large or to small, rsync because it shouldn't have to check for modifications of files since I and the simulation job are the only ones accessing them.

So my idea would be using inotify (see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5515/863)) to detect changes in the simulation directory in a loop and *then* fork into a rsync for the changed files. However I'm not sure whether that might accidentally skip files closed just when the fork is done. <sub>(and possibly I'd also end up in an infinite loop due to inotify calling rsync to sync the just synchronized file again...)</sub> So before I try too much there, I repeat my question:

> Is there a tool that hooks to two directories and synchronizes them as soon as something changes?

(basically this would be something like an offline dropbox, I guess)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [lsyncd](http://code.google.com/p/lsyncd/).

> Lsyncd watches a local directory trees event monitor interface (inotify). It aggregates and combines events for a few seconds and then spawns one (or more) process(es) to synchronize the changes. By default this is rsync. Lsyncd is thus a light-weight live mirror solution that is comparatively easy to install not requiring new filesystems or blockdevices and does not hamper local filesystem performance.

It's not two-way, but from your question I understood you don't need that either. If you need two-way synchronization, [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) is good answer, except there is no inotify support. Also, check out [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/156215/please-help-to-find-a-solution-for-two-way-real-time-synchronization-on-centos-5/156270).

Third thing for two-way synchronization is [DRBD](http://www.drbd.org/), block-level realtime synchronization system, included in mainline kernel. Unfortunately, as it is almost synchronous, it requires fast internet connection.

Comment: +1 lsyncd sounds good, I'll have to invest some time to compile/install it without root permissions and lua installed however :(

Comment: It appears Unison is no longer being actively developed.
http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/status.html