# Execute command when file changes

Tags: command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a bash script be hooked to a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5515/can-a-bash-script-be-hooked-to-a-file)

Hi there,

I am trying to execute a command every time a file changes. Is this possible?
I think there is some way to watch for a file, but I have no idea.

Thank you!

Comment: There are actually a lot of ways to handle this depending on the kind of file, the kind of change, how often it needs to be checked, if there are any requirements for monitoring previous actions, etc. Could you please describe your problem more fully?

Comment: Are you using Linux? If so, the post that @Gilles linked to should do exactly what you need.