# How can I make scripts run when a file/directory changes in Linux (like Mac OS X’s launchd)?

Tags: linux, shell, files, hook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a bash script be hooked to a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5515/can-a-bash-script-be-hooked-to-a-file)

On Mac OS X, there’s a handy daemon called [launchd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd) which (amongst other things) allows you to have scripts run when files or directories change (via the `WatchPaths` and `QueueDirectories` plist file options).

Is there a (preferably Debian) Linux program/package that includes this functionality?