# Trigger action each time a file is modified

Tags: filesystems, files, hook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a bash script be hooked to a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5515/can-a-bash-script-be-hooked-to-a-file)

Is it possible to mount a mechanism to a file to perform an action (e.g. mark the change in some log file and such) each time the file is modified?  I would like to be able to see what all the files modified are in a given time period or receive an alert each time someone modifies a file.

Comment: Probably the linux audit daemon (auditd) can be used for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en) for this if your os and filesystem support inotify.

Comment: I am on RHEL 5.8 -- do have a man page for inotify but couldn't find the exe in the path

Comment: RHEL doesn't ship it, so you need to install it yourself.