# How to make a scheduled task based on a file creation time?

Tags: shell-script, scheduling, job-control

The supercomputer I run my Analysis uses SGE to do the job management and requires each job duration not longer than 24 hours. And this feature is causing me quite a headache.

Sadly, I was asked to use checkpoint mechanism to output results and resubmit the script `qsub myJobScript`. On program's part, it's not difficult for me to have it output a temporary file when the clock time hits 23:30:00 (I give the IO operation half of hour), let's say the output file name is called `1.00137/U` and `1.00137/p`, etc.
*Note: when you submit a job, you never know when it is going to start. but it does have a log file under my folder when it is started.*

So my question is how to use `crontab` or `at` or bash scripts to submit my job automatically when "new files" are created and detected? Any ideas?

Comment: What unix variant is it? For Linux, use an inotify-based mechanism, see [Can a bash script be hooked to a file?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5515)

Answer (score 1):

Run a simple script with `cron` every 5 minutes. Your crontab could look e.g. like this:

```
*/5 * * * *  /path/to/your/script
```

Script pseudocode:

```
IF (lockfile exists) { exit }
create lockfile
IF (old job has not finished yet) { 
    remove lockfile
    exit
}
IF (new job has already been queued) {
    remove lockfile
    exit
}
schedule new task
remove lockfile
```

See [Correct locking in shell scripts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22044/correct-locking-in-shell-scripts) for how to lock correctly (as race-condition-free as possible).