# How to save in a variable the convert from decimal to binary without use an echo

Tags: shell-script, shell, tee

I've been trying to save in a variable the value of the convert of a number from decimal to binary, like this:

```
num1=10
echo "obase=2;$num1" | bc   | tee -a register.txt
```

but I don't want to show it in screen, because the idea is just do the convert and save it in the file like `register.txt`

How can I do so?

Comment: Add a `>/dev/null` at the end.  `num1=10; echo "obase=2;$num1" | bc | tee -a register.txt >/dev/null`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a bash script be hooked to a file?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5515/can-a-bash-script-be-hooked-to-a-file)

Comment: Your original question had `num` = 10`, you should leave out the spaces. Also don't ask if someone can help, that can be answered by "yes"/"or" and doesn't solve your real problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using the `output redirection` as below.

```
$ bc -l <<<"obase=2;$num" > register.txt
```

The above command will overwrite any older results. In case if you want to append your results.

```
$ bc -l <<<"obase=2;$num" >> register.txt
```

`>>` - Redirects output (STDOUT) messages in append mode.

`>`  - Redirects output (STDOUT) messages in overwrite mode.

`<<<` - Here Strings, The word is expanded and supplied to the command on its standard input.

Comment: Note that while `>>` and `>` are standard, `<<<` is a zsh extension (now supported by a few other shells).

Answer (score 1):

The `tee` command is there to split the output, most often used to get text to a file and to the screen.

Just leave it out and use output redirection (appending) to file with `>>`:

```
echo "obase=2;$num1" | bc >> register.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using tee, just use [I/O-Redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) of the shell:

```
echo "obase=2;$num1" | bc >>register.txt
```

The `>>`-statement causes the output to be redirected (`>` redirect, `>>` append) to the file.
The `-a` flag of `tee` causes also an append to the file. You only need `tee` if you want the output to be shown in the shell **AND** redirected to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if your shell is `ksh` or `zsh`, you don't need `bc` to convert to binary¹.

in ksh/zsh:

```
$ typeset -i2 num1=10
$ print -- "$num1"
2#1010
$ print -- "${num1#??}"
1010
```

With `zsh`:

```
$ print -- $(( [##2] num1 ))
1010
```

(zsh doesn't do split+glob upon parameter expansions or arithmetic expansions, so you don't need to quote them, though quoting won't harm).

With `ksh93`:

```
$ num1=10
$ printf '%..2d\n' "$num1"
1010
```

With any of those, add `> register.txt` to redirect that output into a file (replacing its contents, if any), or `>> register.txt` to *append* it to the file (like `tee -a` does; though `tee` also writes its input to its stdout).

---

<sup>¹ unless the number doesn't fit in a 64 bit integer</sup>