# Higher-level wrapper for entr or inotifywait

Tags: shell, files, inotify

I'm looking for a way to rerun a specific command as soon as any of the files in a subdirectory (perhaps minus selected excludes) changes.

## Use case

I'm working on a project that is self-contained in a directory. This project can be compiled, say, using `make`. I want to use the idle time of my machine to repeatedly compile the project. One option is to call `make` once per second, e.g., using `watch (1)`. However, if `make` fails, it will usually fail whenever it's executed again, thus wasting CPU processing power (and, more importantly, heating up my laptop computer).

Instead, there should be a process that watches all files and runs `make` (or whatever other tool) only after anything changes in the directory where the project lives.

## Existing solutions

Others have asked: [Can a bash script be hooked to a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5515/19205) There's `inotifywait (1)`, but it doesn't appear to have a nice interface for repeating a command. Also, there's `entr (1)` which looks like the way to go, but a closer inspection of the [project's website](http://entrproject.org/) reveals that

> [i]t was determined early on that `entr` would not implement it's own file search syntax, relying on standard Unix tools instead.

I'm lazy. I don't want to write a loop for my repeated invocation of `make`. Is there a higher-level magic tool that allows me to write

```
magic make
```

with the effect that `make` is rerun everytime *anything* in the current directory changes?

**NB**: It would be ideal if this magic tool was aware of the inevitable race condition that ensues when using `inotify`: Changes that occur after issuing the call but before a watch is established. I'm not sure if `entr` can do this, it looks like this feature requires keeping track of some kind of snapshot of at least the timestamps of all affected files.

**SHAMELESS SELF-PROMOTION**: My own four-liner that (somewhat) accomplishes this is called [`rpt`](https://github.com/krlmlr/scriptlets/blob/17c5929c22b60b4f417e92dac4c75ff5b5027a77/rpt) and is far from perfect, I'd like to know if I'm duplicating effort here.

Comment: So I can uderstand you need to check file|directory changing and if so do some action(s). As for me it is usual task which can be provided via few tools, for example `cron` (to start check) + find (to modification check).

Comment: @Costas: The action should start immediately after changing files (perhaps after some configurable small delay).

Comment: OK, forget `cron`(which can start check every minute), use `watch` instead (to check every second).

Comment: Additionally you can provide check by files hash-sum instead of modification time.

Comment: @Costas: Added some detail about my use case to the question.

Comment: You can store your dir-hash after `make` completed (e.g. `tar -cf - dir/ | sha1sum - > dir.hash` than test it with `watch -g 'tar -cf - dir/ | sha1sum -c dir.hash' ; make`

Comment: @Costas: Thanks. Is there a tool that encapsulates this functionality behind a neat command-line interface?

Comment: You are free to start script file in background (if I understand your question clear)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `ls <dir> | entr make <file>` would work. Only inotifywait will pick up creation of  files.

If you need to pass filenames use info in comments from this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/81704/346155